# Variable row size list field in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have created an application that contains a list `field(custom)`

If a certain condition is satisfied I  want `rowheight` to be 100, else it should be 50

How can I do that?

I tried `setRowHeight(index,size);` But it didn't work. Moreover it's undocumented to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did some manipulations in the drawListRow method of the custom list field and i could make a list field with variable row size

```
if(mycondition==true)
   setRowHeight(50);
else
   setRowHeight(100);
```

also in drawrow method i wrote

layout(width, 100);

and it worked for me....

but i m still testing it to check whether it works on all devices and in all conditions
and may be some body else help me to make it better!!!!!

Comment: hey i got 1 error
it works only for first row!!!!!

but this can be solved!!!!!!!!!!!
let me have a try